# Firebase Generic withConverter Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, generics, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase to interact with firstore and am taking advantage of the "withConverter" method to handle the mapping of data to and from my domain objects. I want to try and eliminate having to write custom withConverter logic for all my domain objects but keep getting typescript errors when trying to create a generic version. I'm not sure it's even possible.

I want to do something like

```
export function collectionWithConverter<T,D>(TCreator:{new ():T},ref: CollectionReference<DocumentData>): CollectionReference<T> {
  return ref.withConverter({
    toFirestore: (obj: T) => {
      return obj.toFirestoreJSON()
    },
    fromFirestore: (snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot, options: SnapshotOptions) => {
      const data = snapshot.data(options) as D
      return new TCreator({...data, "id": snapshot.id})
    }})
}
```

But I get errors:
'data' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Type 'CollectionReference' is not assignable to type 'CollectionReference'.
Type 'DocumentData' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'DocumentData'

```
export enum ItemCollectionFields {
  ID = "id",
  ITEM_ID = "itemID",
  NAME = "name",
  DESCRIPTION = "descriptionText",
}

const ICF = ItemCollectionFields

export interface ItemProps {
  [ICF.ID]: string,
  [ICF.ITEM_ID]: string,
  [ICF.NAME]: string,
  [ICF.DESCRIPTION]: string|null,
}

export class Item {
  id: string|null = null
  name: string|null = null
  descriptionText: string|null = ""
  constructor(props:Partial<ItemProps>) {
    this[ICF.ID] = props[ICF.ID]
    this[ICF.NAME] = props[ICF.NAME]
    this[ICF.DESCRIPTION] = props[ICF.DESCRIPTION]
  }
  toJSON(): ItemProps {
    return {
      [ICF.ID]: this[ICF.ID],
      [ICF.NAME]: this[ICF.NAME],
      [ICF.DESCRIPTION]: this[ICF.DESCRIPTION],
    }
  }

  toFirestoreJSON(): Partial<ItemProps> {
    const {id, ...rest} = this.toJSON()
    for (const key in rest) {
      if (rest[key] === "" || rest[key] === null || rest[key] === undefined) {
        delete rest[key]
      }
    }
    return rest
  }

  static defaultItem():Item {
    return new Item({id: "", name: "", descriptionText: ""})
  }
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export function getCollectionReference<T>(collectionName:Collections, converter: (ref: CollectionReference<DocumentData>)=>CollectionReference<T>): CollectionReference<T> {
  return converter(firestoreAccessor(collectionName))
}

export function getDocumentReference<T>(collectionName:Collections, itemID:string, converter: (ref: DocumentReference<DocumentData>)=>DocumentReference<T>): DocumentReference<T> {
  return converter(doc(getFirestore(), collectionName, itemID))
}

export function collectionWithConverter(ref: CollectionReference<DocumentData>): CollectionReference<Item> {
  return ref.withConverter({
    toFirestore: (Item: Item) => {
      return Item.toFirestoreJSON()
    },
    fromFirestore: (snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot, options: SnapshotOptions) => {
      const data = snapshot.data(options) as ItemProps
      return new Item({...data, "id": snapshot.id, "itemID": snapshot.id})
    }})
}

export function documentWithConverter(ref: DocumentReference<DocumentData>): DocumentReference<Item> {
  return ref.withConverter({
    toFirestore: (Item: Item) => {
      return Item.toFirestoreJSON()
    },
    fromFirestore: (snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot, options: SnapshotOptions) => {
      const data = snapshot.data(options) as ItemProps
      return new Item({...data, "id": snapshot.id, "itemID": snapshot.id})
    }})
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Example Use case
export async function getItem(itemID: string): Promise<Item|null> {
  const ref = getDocumentReference<Item>(Collections.ITEMS, itemID, documentWithConverter)
  const snap = await getDoc(ref)

  if (snap.exists) {
    return snap.data()
  }
  return null
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Example to convert a database type to a local type (in this example, adding the id from database to the local type):

```js
interface DatabaseType {
  foo: boolean;
}
interface LocalType extends DatabaseType {
  id: string;
}

const converter: FirestoreDataConverter<LocalType> = {
    toFirestore: (item) => item,
    fromFirestore: (snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DatabaseType>, options) => {
      const data = snapshot.data(options);
      return {
        ...data,
        id: snapshot.id
      };
    }
};

const q = query(...).withConverter(converter);
```

Comment: Interesting this might be what I needed. Never had time to go back and try what was suggested below. I guess the trade-off with this approach is all my types I want to use with this need to extend a common interface which maybe they should have been doing anyhow. Thanx

Answer (score 3):

It appears that it’s possible to write a generic `FirestoreDataConverter` object according to this [guide](https://medium.com/swlh/using-firestore-with-typescript-65bd2a602945). The custom object in the guide is written to take from any type, much like you are currently trying to do. I have tested specifically the generic data converter:

```
// Test class
class User{
    constructor(readonly fName: string, readonly lName: string){
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
    }

    toString(): string{
        return `First name: ${this.fName}, Last name: ${this.lName}`;
    }

}

//Generic converter
const genericConverter = <T>() => ({
    toFirestore(data: Partial<T>) {
        return data;
    },
    fromFirestore(snapshot: FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot): T {
        return snapshot.data() as T;
    }
});

//Sample function to get document
async function getFireDocs(){
    const userSnap = await fireDB
        .collection('simpleUser')
        .withConverter(genericConverter<User>())
        .doc('simpleUser1').get();
    const testUser = new User(userSnap.data().firstName, 
userSnap.data().lastName);
    if (testUser !== undefined) {
        console.log(testUser.fName);
        console.log(testUser.lName);
        console.log(testUser.toString());
        console.log(testUser)
    }
}
getFireDocs();
```

Output:

```
John
Smith
First name: John, Last name: Smith
User { fName: 'John', lName: 'Smith' }
```

The complete code from this article is found [here](https://gist.github.com/JamieCurnow/cba3968a7f1e335d473632f9fc9f6e8b). It seems that the use of a [Partial](https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-partial-type-in-typescript-ecfcfbc87cb6) type helps in this case, since it allows properties to be optional of object models. [Here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/global.html#FirestoreDataConverter) is the full `FirestoreDataConveter` documentation with additional examples.

Comment: I found and tried that example before posting and got typescript issues without making any modifications to it. So maybe something was updated that made that not work or I'm missing something.

Comment: I have updated the code snipped in my answer after testing parts of the code from the Medium article I linked, specifically the generic `FirestoreDataConverter`. I’m not sure if your exact functionality is possible to be implemented since the linked Gist also contains multiple helper functions and objects to be useful. This [comment](https://gist.github.com/JamieCurnow/cba3968a7f1e335d473632f9fc9f6e8b#gistcomment-3880812) also seemed interesting to read about the relevant use cases.

Comment: I will give it a try again soon and report back.

Comment: I'm having issues using the generic version when using setDoc() to update, it's complaining about sending a "custom object" to the setDoc method.